# SSL Handshake Error with several Apache Servers

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

I'm running into a strange behaviour with my server setup. I have several apache and application servers behind one another and run into SSL Handshake issues. My Server Setup is

```
Request from Internet to first apache via https
--> forward to second apache via http
    --> forward to application server via https
```

I know that the mixture of http/https is not perfect but I will address that later. The problem is, that my request passes the first apache, reaches the second apache and results in `AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /api/servicename/v1` and `AH01097: pass request body failed to 10.173.121.84:9443 (10.173.121.84) from 10.173.144.43 ()` error messages.

So I assume the problem location is somewhere between my second apache and my application server. And now to the strange part: When I address my second apache directly via IP instead of using a domain name which is proxied through my first apache, the above mentioned error does not appear and my service returns a valid response.

```
Direct request to second apache via http
--> forward to application server via https
```

My first guess was that my first apache needs to work as SSLProxyEngine (`SSLProxyEngine  On`) - the same as my second apache already does. Maybe thats necessary when there is https communication somewhere during the whole request. But that didn't change anything.

The configurations are quite simple.

First Apache

```
# ServerName, ServerAdmin, Logging, etc
##################################################################

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLProxyEngine  On

    ProxyPass /oauth balancer://test-esb-gateway-cluster/oauth
    ProxyPassReverse /oauth balancer://test-esb-gateway-cluster/oauth
    ProxyPass /api balancer://test-esb-gateway-cluster/api
    ProxyPassReverse /api balancer://test-esb-gateway-cluster/api
##################################################################
```

Second Apache

```
# ServerName, ServerAdmin, Logging, etc
##################################################################

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLProxyEngine  On

    ProxyPass /api balancer://esb-api-cluster/api
    ProxyPassReverse /api balancer://esb-api-cluster/api
    ProxyPass /oauth balancer://oauth-provider-cluster/oauth
    ProxyPassReverse /oauth balancer://oauth-provider-cluster/oauth

##################################################################
```

Anybody already ran into this or a similar problem?